# Definition of disconnected subsets in metric spaces and in more general settings

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

I found the following paragraph in a *Real Analysis* book (namely, Carother's one).

> A subset $E$ of a metric space $M$ is *disconnected* in $E$ if there
>   exist disjoint, nonempty, open (in $E$) sets $U$ and $V$ such that $E=
>  U \cup V$. Now, it is immediate that this gives us a pair of open sets
>   $A$ and $B$ in $M$ such that $U=A \cap E$ and $V = B \cap E$. And so
>   "unrelating" the relative definition, by writing it in terms of $A$
>   and $B$, yields: $A \cap E \neq \varnothing$, $B \cap E \neq
>  \varnothing$, $(A \cap E) \cap (B \cap E) = \varnothing$, and $E = (A \cap E) \cup (B \cap E)$, or $E \subset A \cup B$.
>   (Phew!) This mess would be greatly simplified if we could take $A$ and
>   $B$ to be disjoint in $M$. **While this need not hold true in more
>   general settings**, luck is with us in a metric space.

And then Carothers proceeds by giving the following lemma:

> Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space $M$. If $U$ and $V$ are disjoint
>   open sets in $E$, then there are disjoint open sets $A$ and $B$ in $M$
>   such that $U = A \cap E$ and $V = B \cap E$.

I am wondering, what are the more general settings where this lemma does not hold?

Comment: By more general, I imagine you are looking for some examples of topological spaces where the lemma doesn't hold? Since the lemma is true for all metric spaces.

Comment: Try playing around with a very small number of points as your space and sets as your topology.

Comment: @graydad Indeed. Actually, this is also the reason why I added the general-topology tag.

Comment: @Kolmin Then I think Matthew Leingang has a good suggestion. I'd also look into any space with the discrete topology.

Comment: The discrete topology comes from a metric.

Comment: Thanks to both for the hints!

Comment: I can't parse the "$(A \cap E) \cup (B \cap E)$" that appears between "$B \cap E \neq\varnothing$" and "$E \subset A \cup B$".  Is there a missing relation? "$=E$" perhaps?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Yes indeed. I am really sorry, but now I corrected them. Not only there was the "$=E$" missing, but also the "$=\varnothing$" missing.

Comment: Not a problem.  Nice little question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discrete topology comes from a metric: $\rho(x,y) = 1$ if $x\neq y$ and $0$ if $x=y$.  So that won't work for your counterexample.  Instead, look for a small space with a small number of open sets.

After a minute of playing around I found this: Let $X$ be the set $\{x,y,z\}$ with topology generated by the sub-basis $A=\{x,z\}$ and $B=\{y,z\}$.  So these are the only open sets: $\varnothing$, $\{x,y,z\}$, $\{x,z\}$, $\{y,z\}$, and $\{z\}$.

Then $E = \{x,y\}$ is disconnected in $E$.  Using notation as in the definition, we let $U=\{x\}$ and $V=\{y\}$.  Since $U = A \cap E$ and $V = B \cap E$, $U$ and $V$ are open in $E$ (that is, open sets in the subspace topology of $E$).  Clearly $U \cup V=E$ and $U \cap V = \varnothing$.

But there are no *disjoint* open sets in $X$ that separate $E$, as can be checked by experimenting on the five open sets.

Comment: Actually, I did not see immediately your comment regarding the missing relation, because I was playing with sets following your hint. By doing this, I set $M = \{ a, b, c, d \}$, $\tau = \{ \varnothing, M , \{a,b\} \}$, $E = \{ a,b,c\}$, $\tau_E = \{ \varnothing, \{a,b\}, \{b,c\} \}$, and then $U = \{ a, b \}$ and $V = \{c\}$. Thus, the idea is that for every $A, B \in \tau$, if $U =  A \cap E$, then $V \neq B \cap E$. And then indeed it fails. Again, thanks for the hint and the answer!

Comment: @Kolmin: Looks like a good idea.  But is $\tau_E$ supposed to be the subspace topology on $E$?  How do you get $\{b,c\}$ by intersecting an element of $\tau$ with $E$?

Comment: Actually, there are two things here. First, I used a bad notation, because $\tau_E$ looks like the topology induced on $E$ by $\tau$, but really it is not. The second is that –quite naively (or stupidly, if you prefer... :) ) – when I set the example, I did not think at all about it. Thus a new question is, does the construction still work, even if $\tau_E$ is not the relative topology? I mean, of course the counterexample works, but is it not an inner flaw that $\tau_E$ as it stands is not the relative topology?

Comment: @Kolmin: the “in $E$” modifiers all imply that the statement is true in the *subspace topology of* $E$.  So yes, $\tau_E$ should really just be every element of $\tau$ intersected with $E$.

Comment: Ok, now I see. Thus, to make my counterexample work I should simply drop altogether any reference to the $\tau_E$ as I "constructed" it, and leave it as the natural relative topology. Then, it should actually work anyway. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In general, a space $M$ is called *completely normal* if this lemma holds for all subsets of $M$.  A space $M$ is completely normal iff every subspace of $M$ is normal.  In particular, any non-normal space violates this lemma.  Explicitly, if $C$ and $D$ are disjoint closed sets in $M$ which cannot be separated by open sets, then you can take $E=C\cup D$, $U=C$, and $V=D$.

For an example of a very nice (in particular, compact Hausdorff) space in which the lemma fails, consider $M=(\omega_1+1)\times (\omega+1)$, where the ordinals $\omega_1+1$ and $\omega+1$ have the order topology (this space is known as the [Tychonoff plank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_plank)).  Then if $E=\{\omega_1\}\times\omega\cup\omega_1\times\{\omega\}$, the sets $U=\{\omega_1\}\times\omega$ and $V=\omega_1\times\{\omega\}$ are disjoint and open in $E$.  However, there do not exist disjoint open subsets $A,B\subseteq M$ such that $U=A\cap E$ and $V=B\cap E$.  Indeed, if $A$ is an open set containing all of $U$, then it must contain $(\alpha_n,\omega_1]\times\{n\}$ for $\alpha_n$ for each $n$, and therefore contains $(\alpha,\omega_1]\times\omega$ where $\alpha=\sup\alpha_n<\omega_1$.  Then for any $\beta>\alpha$, $A$ intersects every open neighborhood of the point $(\beta,\omega)\in V$, and in particular must intersect any open set containing $V$.